# Contract and asking for raise in IT

Tags: salary, united-states, negotiation, raise

I am a contractor and my contract will be renewed soon (that is, I work in company A through recruitment agency B). I want to ask for a wage raise. Who do I need to ask it? There are two options:

1. My current manager at company A
2. My manager at company B

Comment: which company writes your paycheck?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep company B

Answer (score 3):

You talk to the people who pay you. Which will probably be company B - they'll invoice company A for you, but your contract is with B, even if you turn up at company A each day to work. It's written in your contract.

Answer (score 0):

You have an arrangement with company B. Company B has a contract with company A.

Depending on how the management and budgeting in Company A is done the person who manages your time has no idea how much company A is paying per hour to have you work on their project. They definitely have no idea how much an hour you see in your check after benefits, taxes, and profit are accounted for.

Your avenues are to convince company B to make less profit on your labor, or they have to find a way to charge more for you. Their ability to do that is in the contract. It may have different rates based on your level of skills and experience. If it does have different rates then you need their help to determine what needs to be done to  justify a higher rate for you. There is also the possibility that they have other customers that will pay more for your set of skills and experience.

Now sometimes the contract with company A will allow them to increase your pay every year without impacting their profits. This is an attempt to account for inflation. While nice to get, these raises tend to move very slowly and they are a guess about how inflation will be during the length of the contact between the two companies.

Your manager at company A can help in some cases by making sure that their management knows how valuable you are to the success of their project. It can help company A's management accept a higher rate for you when company B is trying to justify it. Sometimes your manager at company A will write a nice review for you, other times they are not willing to get involved. If they write something for your manager at company B it can help get you a monetary award, but generally doesn't result in a permanent raise.

Answer (score 0):

> I work in company A through recruitment agency B. I want to ask for a
>   wage raise. Who do I need to ask it?

You ask your manager at agency B for a raise. They pay your wages. They are the only ones in a position to change your salary.